# How to add styles except when elements wrap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make elements draw a line from one element to another, but if it breaks or wraps to the next line, I don't want that line to be there. Is there a way to do this and adjust the last item of a row not to have the line?

I know I can do something like:

```
:not(:nth-child(3n))
```

But I need this to be dynamic so it adjusts as the window gets smaller.
Is this possible with pure CSS?

Here is an example, or you can go to this [Pen](https://codepen.io/adventcloud/pen/JBbdeB) if you want to play with the code.

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.child_container {
  max-width: calc(100% - 128px);
}
.child_container .child:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  height: 1px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 17px;
  left: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1px;
}
.child {
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: #6F9FD8;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray; 
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='child_container'>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
    <div class='child'> x </div>
  </div>
  <div class='right'> Cool Stuff </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem seemed to be much less trivial than I thought.
I ended up putting the dash before the circles. And since they are position absolute, they are outside the element border.

All I had to do was hide the overflow.
Here is an updated [Pen](https://codepen.io/adventcloud/pen/JBbdeB)

```
.child_container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child_container .child:before {
  left: -15px;
  //rest of styles 
}
```